# How can we use undefined term "infinity" in limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, real-numbers

Consider function $f$ such that $f:R \to R$ and

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) $$
Now in standard textbooks of calculus such a limit can be found out if it exist. Like for example
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} 1+\dfrac{1}{x^2}=1.$$

But my question is how can limit of $x$ tending to"$\infty"$ can be found if infinity itself is not even defined? Like i know that we are finding limit when $x$ is "very large" but the fact that we are using infinity is not very appealing to me . Instead can we say that$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to M} f(x) $$
where $M$ is such that $\forall m \in R$ $$M>m.$$

But again we do not know what $M$ is.

So can someone clarify this?

Comment: The formal definition of $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=l$ is the following big sentence: *for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $M>0$ such that for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, if $x>M$ then $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$*. Notice that the formal definition never uses $\infty$ anywhere.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = l$ means that $|f(x)-l|$ is guaranteed to be small, provided $l$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Agreed. In other words, while the symbol $\infty$ is not defined, the expression $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is defined. This is one reason why it's important to know the precise definitions of mathematical terms.

Comment: Some textbooks avoid the expression "$x$ tends to infinity" and use instead "$x$ increases without bound" but the meaning (i.e., mathematical content) is the same.  It is true that the formal $\epsilon, M$ definition doesn't mention anything about either $\infty$ or "increasing without bound", but there is still a reason why $\infty$ appears as part of the notation :-)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you keep on studying (pure) maths, eventually you will meet topological spaces and particularly the topological space of the [extended reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line). This is a set that genuinely contains an object called $\infty$, and the notation $\lim_{x \to c}$ has a nice uniform definition for every extended real $c$ (including $\infty$) in terms of topology. But the first time you see limits, the right way to think about it is certainly peek-a-boo's comment - $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ is just a special piece of notation.

Comment: We define two different concepts. One of these might be written as $\color{red}A\color{red}(x\color{red},a\color{red},f(x)\color{red})$ and the other as $\color{green}B\color{green}(x\color{green},f(x)\color{green})$. However, we prefer to write something else instead of $\color{red}A$ and $\color{green}B$, namely $\color{red}\lim_{x\color{red}\to a}f(x)$ and $\color{green}\lim_{x\color{green}\to \color{green}\infty}f(x)$. It is just "by coincidence" that the latter looks somewhat similar to the former and as if the symbol $\infty$ were a numerical value that can be used as $a$.

Comment: @Andrew I suppose you mean "provided $x$ is sufficiently large"? Usually wouldn't pay much attention to such a typo, but might be crucial since the OP is trying to understand a concept which seems muddled to them.

Comment: Every time you see a new use of $\infty$, you have to learn an equivalent restatement without it to understand what you've seen. For example, the explanations herein of $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ are helpful, but you'll have to learn something new again to understand $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

At one time, the Open University (a British institution) decided to solve this problem by abolishing the “$x\to\infty$” notation, replacing it with “$x$ large”. Thus, in their mathematical textbooks, the former notation was nowhere to be seen. Instead we saw such expressions as
$$\lim_{x\,\text{large}}f(x).$$
This was properly explained without reference to any mysterious quantity such as “infinity”.

There is a lot to be said for this approach, which saves people from the confusion which you experience. The downside is that old ways die hard. People who happily used $x\to\infty$ for decades were not going to give up their habit just because it confused people who reason that $x\to\infty$ must be the special case of $x\to a$ when “$a=\infty$”. We are probably going to be stuck with this traditional notation, as we are with other dubious practices, such as writing $\cos^2x$ to mean $(\cos x)^2$ when logically it should mean $\cos\cos x$.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about the limit of a function as $x$ approaches infinity, we're not talking about $x$ reaching a definite number, but rather $x$ growing without bound. So, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ is a way of describing the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x$ becomes arbitrarily large.

The symbol $\infty$ is not a real number, but rather a symbol representing an unbounded quantity. It's a way to talk about the behavior of functions as their inputs grow without limit.

Here is a formal definition: Let $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches infinity is $L$, denoted
$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L,$ means that:

For every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $c > 0$ such that whenever  $+x> c$, we have $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.
$$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)\,(\exists c > 0)\,(\forall x \in S)\,(x > c \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon).$$

So your suggestion of using $\lim_{x\rightarrow M} f(x)$ where M is some number such that $\forall m \in \mathbb{R}, M> m$ doesn't work within the structure of real numbers because there is no real number $M$ that satisfies this property. The notation $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}$ is a well-established convention to describe the idea of $x$ growing without bound.

Answer (score 0):

The formal definition of a limit at infinity, such as $L=\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$, is that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a number $M$ so that if $x>M$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. The use of $\infty$ in the limit can be thought of as a short-hand for this formal limit which is similar to, but different than, an ordinary limit. And others have touched on this.

But the use of $\infty$ is not just decoration or superfluous. It can be made precise and exact. The Extended Real Line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is the set of real numbers appended with $\pm\infty$. There's nothing mysterious about $\infty$, if we're careful we can just toss it in and work with it just fine. Just as open intervals like $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ act as "nearby neighborhoods" of a number $x$, we can do something similar with infinity by saying that the sets $(M,\infty]$ are the nearby neighborhoods of $\infty$ (and similar for $-\infty$). Note that this set gets smaller with larger $M$, so it captures the concept of "sufficiently large".

Limits on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ can then be universally stated as follow: For $r\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ we say that $L=\lim_{x\to r}f(x)$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some "nearby neighborhood" $U$ of $r$ so that if $x\in U$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. In this case $U$ can be $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ which would recover the ordinary definition of a limit or $(M,\infty]$ which gives the infinite case. With this in mind, the statement of an infinite limit in the first paragraph is just a way to do this, but instead of everything just being a special case the different limits need to be broken down into separate cases with separate definitions.